# MySQL PHP GAE Form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, google-app-engine

I have the following form:

```
<h2>Sign the Register</h2>
<form action="sign.php" method="post"> 
<div><textarea name="firstName" rows="3" cols="60" placeholder="First Name..." required="true"></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="surname" value="mickey" rows="3" cols="60" placeholder="Surname..." required="true"></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="course"  value="mickey" rows="3" cols="60" placeholder="Your Course..." required="true"></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="subject" rows="3" cols="60" placeholder="Subject..." required="true"></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="level" rows="3" cols="60" placeholder="Level: C, I, H, M..." required="true"></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="date" rows="3" cols="60" placeholder="Date.." required="true"></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="time" rows="3" cols="60" placeholder="Time.." required="true"></textarea></div>
<div><input type="submit" value="Sign Register"></div>
```

And sign.php is (the connection is fine):

```
{
if (array_key_exists('firstName', 'surname', 'course', 'subject', 'level', 'date', 'time', $_POST)) {
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO entries (firstName, surname, course, subject, level, date, time) VALUES (:firstName, :surname, :course, :subject, :level, :date, :time)');
$stmt->execute(array(':firstName' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstName']),
':surname' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['surname']),
':course' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['course']),
':subject' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']),
':level' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['level']),
':date' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['date']),
':time' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['time'])));
 $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

 }
 }
 $db = null;
 ?>
```

And when that is executed the user is taken to a following page which has the following:

```
    <?php

          try {
// Show existing entries.
foreach($db->query('SELECT * from entries') as $row) {
        echo "<div><strong>" . $row['firstName'] . "</strong> wrote <br> " . $row['course'] . "</div>";
 }
  } catch (PDOException $ex) {
echo "An error occurred in reading or writing to register.";
  }
  $db = null;
?>
```

But the problem is that none of the records are showing on the success page. I am using google app engine with cloud SQL database (the connection is fine). It is basically a form, the user fills in the form and then the data is sent to the cloud sql database. Also once the user submits the form, they are taken to a page which displays the information that is just been submitted. Any easier/better ways of doing this are welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) expects only two parameters (key,array) you should split

> if (array_key_exists('firstName', 'surname', 'course', 'subject', 'level', 'date', 'time', $_POST))

into multiple conditions

```
if(array_key_exists('firstName', $_POST) && array_key_exists('surname', $_POST) ... array_key_exists('time', $_POST))
```